If approved at the interview in London for the USA non-immigrant B1/B2 visa application, will the visa be provided immediately?
I'm wondering if I will be approved at the interview in London for my non-immigrant B1/B2 visa application, whether I will get the visa stuck into my passport immediately, or need to wait a further number of days/weeks after the interview?
I applied on 17 July 2024, have been provided with an earliest interview date of 24 September 2024, and am due to travel on 4 October 2024.

I voted to reopen; the question posed as "duplicate" isn't. That question asked if the applicant is advised of the "grant/deny" decision at the time of the interview; this question asks a different question: whether, if the application is granted, the visa foil will be attached to the passport at the interview, or must the application wait some time (days or weeks) for the passport to be returned to the applicant. Different questions ≄ duplicates.

@DavidRecallsMonica But most answers to the putative duplicate indicate that while the decision was (usually) made on the spot, the passport is mailed back to the applicant: the visa isn't added there and then. As such, it seems to answer this question. (Whether a mailed passport reaches the OP in the time frame needed is unanswerable and depends on the post).

I accepted the duplicate because indeed most of the answers there were informative that the generation of the visa foil is not immediate. I suppose there’s still a chance that, under certain circumstances, this part could be expedited at the embassy in which case that could be elucidated in an answer here
